# Will a dual car charger that shows a maximum output of 2000mA produce a 2.1A current?

Tags: power-supply, power, charger, output, dual

I have a dual car charger that states input is 12-24VDC and Output is maximum of 2000mA, but it is supposed to have one port charge at 1A and other port charge at 2.1A. Is the 2.1A output possible with 2000mA or does it have to be 2100mA to produce and output of 2.1A?

Comment: In engineering 2.0 is often 2.1, except on bank holidays down hill with the wind behind you. It MAY help to explain where the various statements came from. eg "is maximum of 2000 mA" -> who says so and where do they say it? | "It is supposed to have ... at 2.1A" -> who says so and where do they say it? Why are there two "xxx says" and why do they contradict each other and have you reason to trust one or other or neither (or both)? | I'd say there is a reasonable chance that it may produce 2.1 A. Stay away from bank holidays .

Comment: datasheet? model number? manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

2000mA is 2A. There is no way to get 2.1A from it at the rated specs. And you can't get 1A and 2A from it either, as that would require 3A total.

Comment: Ok, so a dual charger that shows 2000mA cannot have one of its ports as 2.1A output? I know that if using both ports together it will not allow the 2.1A port to put out the full power.

Comment: Not if you want it to be at a full 5V.

Comment: hmmmm....interesting....so many show 2.1A but with only 2000mA.....

Comment: @ayanna: of course it *can*: the 2000 mA marking can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there are two outputs. One is rated for 12-24VDC and 1A, the other is 12-24VDC and 2.1A. If one port can supply 2.1A, then you can get 2A from it without any problems (you can get anything from 0 to 2.1A from it). If, however, the second port is rated for 2A (which is more likely, and I think what you meant), then no, it will not provide 2.1A. It will provide the specified voltage, and supply 2A to your device, but current and voltage will both be limited to the specified ranges.

Answer (score 1):

These two port chargers are common. The way they work is this. A common switching IC takes 12V auto power input (12~14V nominal, or 24~28V nominal for 24V cars or RVs), and outputs it to a common rail. The usb ports conform to the USB Battery Charging Standard OR the Apple iPhone/iPad Standard, with resistors used to signal what kind of port each should be. The phone or tablet or other device connected then knows how much current it should be allowed to pull.

That being 1.0A iPhone ports or 2.1A iPad ports. But like I said, the charger has a single common output rail. And the signaling resistors, are just that, **SIGNALING** resistors. There is **no current limiting in the charger**. Connecting a 5V 2A load to either usb port's power pins and it can pull 2A without problem. Connect a 5V 3+ Amp load, and your going to overdraw the Switching IC, or Inductor, or Diode, or Wiring.

Ideally, the charger should have parts that cover the full draw plus some. That being 3.1A for a 2.1A + 1A charger, 4.2A for 2x 2.1A chargers, etc. But most don't. Common 1A chargers often have a MC34063, which can only do 750mA output with it's internal mosfet. So they lie about the current sourcing capacity.

**To answer your direct question,** if your charger says max output 2000mA, that means that it most likely can only output 2A max. That's only -5% less than 2.1A, you won't see much of a difference. You could charge two 1A devices, or a single 2.1A device.